# Radio button sends value as Male=on or Female=on.I want to send only Male/Female to Database

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, web, radio-button

My code below has a radio button in the form to select the Sex. But on submitting it's sending as  Male=on or Female=on.I want to send only Male/Female to Database. Please tell me the necessary editing I should do. I'm using Bootstrap.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Home - Student Registration Form</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      .error{
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <form id="regform" class="form-horizontal">
          <fieldset>
          <!-- Form Name -->
          <legend>Student Registration</legend>
          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control input-md">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control input-md">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="dob">Date of birth</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="dob" name="dob" type="text" placeholder="Date of birth" class="form-control input-md">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="age">Age</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="age" name="age" type="text" placeholder="Age" class="form-control input-md" disabled>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="sex">Sex</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
               <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Male">Male</label>
                     <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Female">Female</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Select Basic -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="subjects">Subjects</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <select id="subjects" name="subjects" class="form-control">
                <option value="Database">Database</option>
                <option value="ADA">ADA</option>
                <option value="Networking">Networking</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Textarea -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="localaddress">Local Address</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <textarea class="form-control" id="localaddress" name="localaddress"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="localaddresscheckbox">Permenant address</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <label class="checkbox-inline" for="localaddresscheckbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="localaddresscheckbox" id="localaddresscheckbox" value="1">
                Copy Local Address to permanent Address
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Textarea -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="permenantaddress">Permenant Address</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <textarea class="form-control" id="permenantaddress" name="permenantaddress"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Button -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      (function() {

        jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
          return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
        }, "Letters only please");

        $("#regform").validate({
          rules: {
            dob: "required",
            localaddress: "required",
            permenantaddress: "required",
            firstname: {
                lettersonly: true,
                required: true
            },
            lastname: {
                lettersonly: true,
                required: true
            }
          },
          submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
          }
        });

        //init datepicker
        $('#dob').datepicker({
            'format': 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            'autoclose': true
        });

        //copy localaddress to permenant address on checkbox click
        $('#localaddresscheckbox').click(function(){
          if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var localaddress = $('#localaddress').val();
            $('#permenantaddress').val(localaddress); //copy local address to permenant address box
          }
          else {
            $('#permenantaddress').val('');
          }
        });

        //age handler
        $('#dob').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
          //get current date
          var today = new Date();
          var currentYear = today.getFullYear(); //current year
          var selectedYear = $(this).val().split('-')[0]; //selected dob year
          var age = Number(currentYear) - Number(selectedYear);
          $('#age').val(age);
        });

      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding a value to the radiobutton `<input type="radio" name="Male" value="male">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to name both radios the same name and give them unique values:

```
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male">Male</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female">Female</label>
```

Keep in mind that if they don't select either in this example, the "sex" value will not be sent to your script at all.

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned in my comment just add a value see fiddle for example https://jsfiddle.net/5egjjv91/1/

```
Click on these two radio buttons to see the diference
<input type="radio" name="Male" id="male" onclick="value1()">
<input type="radio" name="Male" id="male2" value="male" onclick="value2()">
<script>
  function value1(){
   var male = document.getElementById('male').value; 
   alert(male);
  }
  function value2(){
   var male2 = document.getElementById('male2').value; 
   alert("This is what the value of male is "+male2);
  }
</script>
```